# Get file and line number for tag with name

Tags: tags

I would like to make simple utility that opens tag under cursor in popup window introduced in recent vim version. Assuming I get word under cursor with command `let l:word = expand("<cword>")`, how would I find if tag with that name exists, in which file and on which line number? I know you can use `taglist` function, but I don't see line number there.

Thanks,
Vjekoslav

Answer (score 1):

`taglist()` is not bound to know the line number at all. Rather it's a command to locate the tag stored in `cmd` field.

As a special case, `cmd` could also contain line number, as number is a valid Ex command too. But that depends on how the tag list was generated.

Comment: Is there a generic way to extract line number from `cmd`?

Comment: @Vjekoslav What do you mean by a "generic way"? It could be a number or not number at all.

Comment: But what happens when `cmd` its not a number? Vim has to evaluate it and then make a jump to a location (file + line). I'm interested in how to obtain that information. I quess I could always let the vim handle that part, jump to location, record it, then go back and do my thing. But that seems extra work...

Comment: @Vjekoslav From `:h taglist()` "The ex-command "cmd" can be either an ex search pattern, a line number or a line number followed by a byte number." Is it a problem to do runtime-checking?

Comment: Its not a problem. I just checked ccomplete.vim and it contains some examples of parsing `cmd`. But its a lot more code than I expected :(. I might end up using method I mentioned above. Let the vim do the jump, record, jump back. Use recorded info.

Answer (score 0):

Could use `ex` command to extract the line number:

```
system(printf("ex -u NONE %s <<< 'set nomagic | %s=' ", file, cmd))
```

Comment: There's a lot in that one-liner. I would appreciate it very much if you could explain what's going on and how it solves the question. Thanks in advance.